# How does server virtualization increase performance?

Tags: virtualization, performance

I was reading about server virtualization as a new trend because of many benefits it brings. One of them is to increase performance with fewer hardware.

How is it possible? From my limited knowledge, no virtualization can match the physical performance (cause you add 1 extra software). And if you decrease the number of physical hardware (1 less computer for example), how can you get the same performance?

Comment: It is more than it can better use your ressources by having less machines but with an higher ratio of ressources usage. Serverfault is not about this kind of question so mostly, this topic is gonna get moved or closed.

Comment: You're correct that raw performance won't match. Virtualization may permit you to more effectively use your available resources, though, if done properly.

Comment: Maybe you can use better your RAM with memory deduplication, ie if you have two identical operating systems, the same pages will be (hopefully) share the same physical RAM

Comment: @Fredi this is true. However, memory deduplication can happen at the OS level regardless of whether virtualization is involved. An excellent example of this is KSM in Linux.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M, what you say it's true, but think about operating system binaries, having two identical operating systems running virtualized on the same physical machine you can keep in real RAM only one copy, while with Linux KSM (which is very nice BTW) you cant.

Comment: Keep in mind that KSM was developed as a helper for KVM, not as an all-purpose memory deduplicator. The fact that it works for other things just shows how awesome Linux is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were reading, but this "new trend" is over a decade old, without considering the fact it's just a reinvention of the mainframe tech. In any case, you might see some performance increase when the host isn't overloaded and the VM workloads can be cached. Otherwise, the benefit is in the hardware utilization ratios, not in performance.

Answer (score 4):

Your question takes into account per-node performance, a value that is far too broad to be considered in every situation. This question largely depends on how one conceptualizes performance.

In practical scenarios, people care about how well a *service* performs, not whether the machine it resides on meets an arbitrary specification of performance metrics. Yes, virtualization involves a degree of overhead. However, it also provides a high degree of isolation and flexibility.

Consider the impact of running multiple services on a single machine, all services given the same pool of resources. In this scenario, one service may consume too much CPU time or memory, such that another service cannot serve its content as optimally as it would given a more limited but *isolated* pool of resources. To solve this with virtualization, services are kept apart from one another as much as possible so that thy may not interfere with one another to the possible detriment of an entire stack.

Also consider features rather than only raw performance. Virtual machines may be moved (on most hypervisors) from host to host *while online*. This allows a host to be vacated of virtual machines before it is brought down for maintenance. During this time, the actual production stack is unaffected and not degraded. This makes it very easy to replace hardware, and makes physical resources generally fungible.

Virtual machines can be of multiple entirely different OS types on the same host, allowing a datacenter to be more flexible and diverse while at the same time homogenizing the lower end of the stack for consistent results and management.

In the spirit of speaking of performance, virtual machines can utilize paravirtualizationto reduce overhead, either of the entire VM, or of specific critical devices in an emulated VM. This allows very near native speeds (and in some cases even greater speeds due to advanced caching features) of flexible disk abstractions, direct disk connections, and virtual NICs. Also, hypervisors utilize advanced memory features such as deduplication that a guest OS may not be capable of. This would allow something like a Windows guest to directly take advantage of deduplication of memory using KSM, and the storage resiliency of BTRFS or ZFS, to make an example.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that virtualisation **doesn't** increase performance. In fact, [virtualisation significantly reduces performance](https://altechnative.net/virtual-performance-or-lack-thereof/).

Granted, I did this testing a while back, but there is no way to get away from the massive overhead of extra context switching. Context switching under a hypervisor is typically about 100x slower than on bare metal. Once you start to approach the CPU saturation point, performance tanks dramatically.

Granted, I did this testing back in Core2 days, but things haven't changed as much as you might expect. There are ways to mitigate the overhead to some extent, including:
1) Pin vCPUs to physical CPU threads (and sacrifice VM migratability).
2) Leave a couple of cores unallocated to the guests and pin the hypervisor to them (and sacrifice those few cores' worth of performance pre-emptively)
3) Increase the minimum time slice duration (typically using an appropriate tuned-adm profile).

But there will still remain a significant overhead.